# Ng-checked not trigger ng-model

Tags: angularjs

> html

```
<input id="cAllBtn" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll"  />

<div ng-repeat="u in $ctrl.usersList" >
 <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAll" ng-model="u.selected"   />
</div>
```

> relevent part in ctrl

```
usersList = [selected:false,selected:false]
```

when i click `cAllBtn` all cbxs in ng-repeat are marked but array not updating 
what to do?

Comment: According to the Official Documentation, you shouldn't use `ng-checked` and `ng-model` on the same element. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: so what th solution?

Comment: there is a potential solution in the marked duplicate.  For what you are trying to do, instead of `checkAll` being a separate property, your check all should call a function that sets the value of all the relevant array elements in the controller.